# How do I alternate between printing elements from two different arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I have two 2D arrays that are both 3x3.

And I want to print out a border and spaces in between like this:

```
|      |
|      |    Note: 6 spaces " " per row / 3 spaces " " per cell 
|      |
```

My thought process in doing so would be to treat the 2D array like a coordinate system, and assign the outer edges to equal 1 to indicate to print a border "|" for the border[][]. Then I would assign 3 spaces for each cell for space[][]. Then I would go row by row and alternate print statements for border[][] and space[][].

So, going row by row it would be.

```
print left border -> print spaces -> don't print border -> print spaces -> print right border -> print spaces
```

Or to clarify a little more on what I want to do:

```
border[0][0] = 1 --> print left border "|"
space[0][0] = 1 --> print space "   "
border[0][1] = 0 --> DO NOT print border "|"
space[0][1] = 1 --> print space "   "
border[0][2] = 1 --> print border "|"
space[0][2] = 1 --> print space "   "
```

So the first row would be:

```
 |      |
```

and so on for every row.

---

**So my question is:**

How do I alternate between printing elements from two different arrays?

---

I've tried

```
    int border[][] = new int[3][3];
    int space[][] = new int[3][3];

    for(int i=0;i<border.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<space.length;j++){
            //Assigning Left and Right borders
            border[0][j] = 1;
            border[border.length-1][j] = 1;
            //Assigning spaces for every cell
            space[i][j] = 1;

            //Printing????
            if(border[i][j] == 1){
                System.out.print("|");
            }

            if(space[i][j] == 1){
                System.out.print("   ");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

but this prints out

```
|   |   |   

|   |   |
```

Comment: You mean like an `if` statement

Comment: I'm not clear on this. You're storing the border? Isn't that like storing the donut hole? I don't mean to be smart, I don't see why you would store anything but the spaces (assuming the spaces are the "substance").

Comment: It's part of a larger problem. Essentially, I am trying to make a grid.

Comment: A more realistic picture of what you're trying to do would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand you. There are a few things you missed, like an else block and I suggest you review my comments below carefully,

```
int border[][] = new int[3][3];
int space[][] = new int[3][3];
for (int[] b : border) {  // <-- lets first create border arrays
  b[0] = b[2] = 1;        // <-- combine the 1s.
  b[1] = 0;              
}
for (int[] s : space) {   // <-- now space arrays
  s[0] = s[1] = s[2] = 1; // <-- combine the 1s.
}
// Now border and space are setup
for (int i = 0; i < border.length; i++) { 
  for (int j = 0; j < border[0].length; j++) {
    if(border[i][j] == 1) {
        System.out.print("|");
    } else { // <-- You need an else block
      System.out.print(" ");          
    }
    if(space[i][j] == 1){ // <-- space is pointless. This is always true.
        System.out.print("   ");
    }
  }
  System.out.println(); // <-- new line.
}
```

Output is your requested

```
|       |   
|       |   
|       |
```